# Retrieve Subscription Data on subscriber

Tags: sql-server, replication

I would like to retrieve the subscription data from a SQL server subscriber. The data that I am looking for is the same data that is displayed under the Local Subscriptions folder under Replication folder in the Object Explorer. The trick is that I only want to see the data (ie subscriptions) that is listed in the folder in object explorer and nothing else. I have poked around in the merge replication tables on the databases on the subscriber and although I can retrieve the subscription information from there, there is invalid data among the masses which I think is due to replication cleanups that was not done properly in the past. There must be a way that SQL server retreives the data in the object explorer and displays it but how? and from where? The reason for this is to compare these subscriptions with the publications and determine any orphaned subscriptions. Any help will be appreciated.